# How to handle/detect screen touched even if a button is touched android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I try to check if screen is touched anywhere, but when I touch an element that already have an `onClickListener`, it cancels my `onTouch` action...

But I want to conserve button action AND global screen touch actions

Thanks for help

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var myButton: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        myButton = findViewById(R.id.myButton)

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Do some stuff.
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // Do other stuff
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return false in your OnTouchListener then your OnClickListener will be also triggered.

Comment: It doesn't worked... it looks like the button overrides `onTouchEvent` actions